# How to compute the Lagrange remainder of a Taylor expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion

In a Taylor expansion with Lagrange remainder, how can I compute the remainder $R_n(x)$?
How to find the $(n+1)$th derivative? Please explain it with elementary functions like $\ln(x),\sin x$ and $\cos x$

Comment: What is the $\;n-$th derivative of $\,\log x\,,\,\sin x\,,\,\cos x\;$ ? It's easy to reach a general formula for each of these.

Comment: For many functions with nice Taylor expansions, high-order derivatives are hard to get a closed form for, and are not a useful way to obtain estimates. Exceptions are $\ln(1+x)$, $\cos x$, $\sin x$ where high order derivatives are easy, and estimates are not difficult, though the Lagrange estimate for $\ln(1+x)$, $-1\lt x\lt 1$, is not good.

Comment: For sinx the nth derivative is $\pm$ sinx or $\pm$ cosx. Then in the remainder for f$^{n+1}$(z) what should be used

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Lagrange form of the remainder term, you cannot find an exact expression for it. This is because of the $n + 1$ derivative term taken at *some* point between $a$ and $x$ ($a$ is the point where you are finding the Taylor expansion) but doesn't say for which *exact* point between $a$ and $x$. What it is useful for is to get bounds for the remainder term (I am hoping someone else will show an example since I don't have time). For functions like $e^x$ and $\sin(x)$, you can use the bounds to show that the remainder term approaches $0$ as you take larger $n$. This means that those functions actually *equal* its Taylor *series*.